# I want to use c++ code on .net NanoFramework how can i do it?

Tags: nanoframework

I have created a library and i get a folder called Stubs
in this folder i get a bunch of files, how can i build it and used as an interrupt on the C# code?

[image: files]

[image: csharp]

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question , good luck .

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post with detailed explanations on how to use Interop in .NET nanoFramework. Please see [here](https://jsimoesblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/interop-in-net-nanoframework).

Look at section *"Adding the Interop library to a nanoCLR image"*. You have to add those files and the respective CMakelists.txt to the project folder and build a new image that includes them.